# Deployed NextJS Tailwind site to production loses interactivity on iOS web broswers

Tags: ios, next.js, tailwind-css

My deployed sites loses interactivity on 16.6.1 iOS chrome and safari browser.
Clicks on `a`, `button` and `textarea` doesn't produce any action.

I am using `"next": "13.4.12"` and `"tailwindcss": "3.3.3"`

I placed `'use client'` in wrapper component containing other components with mentioned html tags. Eventually that component trough other components is imported in home screen `page.tsx` located in `src/app`

Did anyone experience same issues?